# Wrapping a 4-dimensional std::vector of std::complex<float> with SWIG

Tags: c++, swig, stdvector, multidimensional-array, complex-numbers

I have a problem wrapping a 4-dimensional std::vector containing std::complex values. It's basically a matrix with 2 degrees of freedom, therefore 4 dimensional. As matrix sizes vary with those, using nested vectors seemed to be sensible to me (correct me if I'm wrong).

So the data type looks like

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector< std::vector<gr_complex > > > > my4dimvec;
```

To make it accessible in python, I created the following .i file:

```
/* -*- c++ -*- */

#define DRMRX_API

%include "gnuradio.i"           // the common stuff

%{
#include "drmrx_conf.h"
#include "drmrx_params.h"
%}

//load generated python docstrings
%include "drmrx_swig_doc.i"

namespace std {
    %template()     vector< std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > >;
    %template()     std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< gr_complex > > > > ;
};

%include "drmrx_conf.h"
%include "drmrx_params.h"
```

gr_complex is a typedef'd std::complex done in gnuradio.i. By the way, the 4-dimensional int-vector works just fine.

The compile error I get is

```
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx: In instantiation of ‘const char* swig::type_name() [with Type = std::complex<float>]’:
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3530:65:   required from ‘static swig_type_info* swig::traits_info<Type>::type_info() [with Type = std::complex<float>; swig_type_info = swig_type_info]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3537:41:   required from ‘swig_type_info* swig::type_info() [with Type = std::complex<float>; swig_type_info = swig_type_info]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3571:14:   required from ‘static PyObject* swig::traits_from_ptr<Type>::from(Type*, int) [with Type = std::complex<float>; PyObject = _object]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3577:58:   required from ‘static PyObject* swig::traits_from<Type>::from(const Type&) [with Type = std::complex<float>; PyObject = _object]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3596:39:   required from ‘PyObject* swig::from(const Type&) [with Type = std::complex<float>; PyObject = _object]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4635:4:   [ skipping 7 instantiation contexts ]
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4658:54:   required from ‘static PyObject* swig::traits_from<std::vector<T> >::from(const std::vector<T>&) [with T = std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float> > >; PyObject = _object]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3596:39:   required from ‘PyObject* swig::from(const Type&) [with Type = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float> > > >; PyObject = _object]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4635:4:   required from ‘static PyObject* swig::traits_from_stdseq<Seq, T>::from(const sequence&) [with Seq = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float> > > > >; T = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float> > > >; PyObject = _object; swig::traits_from_stdseq<Seq, T>::sequence = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float> > > > >]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4658:54:   required from ‘static PyObject* swig::traits_from<std::vector<T> >::from(const std::vector<T>&) [with T = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float> > > >; PyObject = _object]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3596:39:   required from ‘PyObject* swig::from(const Type&) [with Type = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float> > > > >; PyObject = _object]’
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:6680:894:   required from here
/home/felixwunsch/src/gr-drm/gr-drmrx/build/swig/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3520:77: error: ‘type_name’ is not a member of ‘swig::traits<std::complex<float> >’
make[2]: *** [swig/CMakeFiles/_drmrx_swig.dir/drmrx_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [swig/CMakeFiles/_drmrx_swig.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Thank you,
Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, somehow I solved it myself. The solution was not only to define the 4-dimensional vector but also the 1-2-and-3-dimensional vectors. Final template part now looks like

```
namespace std {
%template()     vector< std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > >;
%template()     std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< gr_complex > > >;
%template()     std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< gr_complex > > > >;
};
```

The 1- and 2-dimensional versions have been declared before in the gnuradio.i file, so I didn't list them here.